# Visual Studio 2010 XML Comment Visualizer

Tags: visual-studio-addins

I've seen references to this addin but it looks like this addin has been lost in the internet void but i've seen another sample like this that is a bit more greyed out. Does anyone know of any addin's like this that auto hide xml comments and displays them nicely like this?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

That came from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx but no code/dll available...

Comment: Yeah that's what i found, the alternative is to create my own, anyone know where i could get a template to help start me off?